# How to post original file as formdata using api with filestack in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using filestack in react to upload files. First i browse the images and upload it, on 
Upload Done i am using a function, in this function i want to post original file as formdata 
using my api with post method. So help me to post original file to my server after getting 
response from filestack upload.

```
const options = {
  maxFiles: 5,
  onUploadDone: handleUploadFunction // callback function on upload done
};

const filestack = client.init("key", options);
const picker = filestack.picker(options);

function handleUploadFunction(result, board_id) {
  const fileData = result.filesUploaded[0];
  console.log(result);
  const getValue = sessionStorage.getItem("user_id");
  const token = sessionStorage.getItem("userToken");

  let imageData = new FormData();

  imageData.append("v_code", "1.0");
  imageData.append("apikey", "41bbf547d64c309749b613f16323b762");
  imageData.append("token", token);
  imageData.append("userid", getValue);
  imageData.append("board_id", 362);
  imageData.append("img_text", "Test Image 362");
  imageData.append("img_data", "image data 362");
  imageData.append("card_id", 8854);
  imageData.append("image", fileData.originalFile);

  axios.post("http://160.153.247.88:3000/add_file", imageData).then(res => {
    console.log(res.data);
  });
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is your problem? Do you get an error?

Comment: in console.log(res.data), i am getting  error not successful response.